Is it possible to compile programs that use ATL using GCC (MinGW or otherwise) given it uses __try?
I'm confused how people use MinGW to compile Windows programs.
I tried using it, but headers like atlalloc.h and atlcom.h use __try in a few ways... which no version of GCC appears to support, for example:
__declspec(noinline) inline bool _AtlVerifyStackAvailable(_In_ SIZE_T Size) {
    bool bStackAvailable = true;
    __try {
        ...

How do people compile Windows programs with GCC-based toolchains? Do they simply avoid ATL altogether? Or is there some way to make ATL work with these?

ATL ships with Visual Studio only, it's also a licensing requirement. And compiling Windows program with something else than MSVC and the official Windows SDK is always a challenge, I always recommend not to do it (MinGW headers for Windows are manually rewritten and are never up-to-date or missing some)

Out of curiosity: why don't you use MSVC ?

Atl isn't necessary for writing windows programs, it's part of msvc and won't work with other compilers

@wohlstad: I mean, I am. I wanted to try GCC though, every compiler has its own strengths.

@user541686 GCC definatly has its strengths (e.g. for cross platform infrastructure). But when it comes to specific Windows programming and using libraries like ATL I would go only (as long as I can) with MSVC.

@SimonMourier: I'm not sure what you mean by a licensing requirement here, does the license somehow prevent using those headers with MinGW GCC on Windows? And yeah it's a challenge, but this is the only part I'm not sure how to solve without modifying the headers.

I'm not a lawyer, but you must have Visual Studio to have ATL (you can't copy the header files somewhere), ATL is not part of Windows, nor part of the Windows SDK, and it's not explicited as a Visual Studio redistributable. And the challenge has nothing to do with GCC, but with the headers and libs.

@SimonMourier: you can run MinGW GCC on Windows with Visual Studio installed, I don't see the issue. Nobody was suggesting this is being done without VS being installed.

Well, nobody says otherwise either. "How do people compile Windows programs with GCC-based toolchains" doesn't mention that obviously Visual Studio is also installed
